# f$_{a}$(x)=d(a,x)−d(a$_{0}$,x) is a bounded continuous map, i.e. f$_{a}$∈F$_{b}$(X;R)∩C(X;R)

Tags: real-analysis

Let (X,d) be a metric space and fix a point a$_{0}$∈X.

a)Prove that for every a∈X, the map f$_{a}$:(X,d)→(R,|⋅|), given by
f$_{a}$(x)=d(a,x)−d(a$_{0}$,x) is a bounded continuous map, i.e. f$_{a}$∈F$_{b}$(X;R)∩C(X;R).

b)Prove that the map Φ:(X,d)→(F$_{b}$(X,R),ρ) given by Φ(a)=f$_{a}$ is an isometry

I'm honestly not even sure where to start with this question, any help with even starting would be appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Hint: show, by definition, that the map that sends x to d(a,x) is continuous. From this you can deduce your function is continuous, and hence bounded.

(b) To answer this I need to know what is the space (Fb,b(X,R),ρ)? More specifically, what is the metric \rho?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: the metric is referring to the distance associated with the norm-infinity. How would I start by showing that the map that sends x tp d(a,x) is continuous, just by definition?

Comment: To show continuity, notice that d(a,x) - d(a,y) \leq d(x,y) by triangular inequality.

Comment: For the second part, I am a bit uncertain whether (Fb,b(X,R),ρ) defines a metric space (e.g. for what a is f_a “zero”?) Let’s even grant that it is a metric space. But the sup norm of f_a is d(a,a_0) (triangle inequality), which is not necessarily equal to |a|. So I don’t see how \Phi can be an isometry.

Comment: I managed to figure out part a, but part b is still stumping me. taking two arbitrary values in f_a and then applying \phi would give us two functions in Fb, if the distance between these two values and two functions is the same then we have an isometry, but I'm not sure how we would compare these two distances? since \phi(a) = f_a (mapping a value to a function)